# Performance Zend Soap Service on LAMP

Tags: performance, web-services, zend-framework, lamp

I have developed 2 soap webservices in my zend application. In my development environment (MAMP on mac 8 GB ram i7 processor) the performance is really good. When I deploy it on my Ubuntu LAMP server (1 GB RAM 1 processor) the performance decreases a lot. Its more than 10 times slower.

I have a java client (eclipse autogenerated client from wsdl) The problem is that the first call is always 4 times slower than the second one. This goes for both my MAMP and LAMP.

MAMP
- First call 400 ms
- Second call 100 ms

LAMP
- First call 2 000 ms
- Second call 400 ms

I simply duplicate the request so the request is exactley the same for the first and second call.

If I manually run the LAMP client several times the first call will be done at around 900 ms. It feels as if the Zend application has to "startup" something during the first call.

Does anyone have any clue on how I can get around this? What I've tried:

- Make sure the wsdl is cached
- Installed xcache (not shipped with LAMP)
- Read tunings tutroials

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

This performance issue often occurs when you use Zend_Soap_AutoDiscovery for wsdl generation. If that is the case for your code, you should consider storing your generated wsdl as a separate xml file and load it in the Zend_Soap_Server constructor.

Comment: I tried storing the wsdl in my public folder and load it in the constructor bot with ./wsdl/my.wsdl and wsdl/my.wsdl. The problem seems to occur when the service hasn't been access for a couple of seconds. If run it several times in a row the call is done in 150 ms in soap-ui (that caches the wsdl) and in about 900 ms in my java client that caches the wsdl in memory. But on occasions, when the service hasn't been access for a couple of minutes/seconds the java client take 2-5 seconds and soap-ui takes 1-2 seconds. Any other ideas?

Comment: You may try to profile your server code with xdebug and kcachegrind to see where exactly is the bottleneck

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a problem with opcode cache. Without opcode cache, Zend's really slow. And it gets a ncie boost when using it.

I'd look for Zend Optimizer, eAccelerator, or simillar...

That would be why it slows down after some idle time (classes/files are wiped from IO cache).

Comment: Thanks, I use xCache. Could you give me some tips on how to tune it to keep my app running (not going into idle).

Comment: Sorry, I have no actual experience with XCache. Solution would be prolonging the lifetime of all caches, but how... I don't know. It's just a pointer ;)

Comment: Could fastcgi be an option? If Ive done a LAMP installation and I see that the mod_cgi is loaded, how can I cahange that to be fastcgi?

Comment: Not sure. ZendServer uses FCGI, and it's really fast. If you can you should try it - Zend Server CE (Comunity Edition) - it's free i guess ;)